# Geometry nodes, randomizing the height on the Z axis for distributed points

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a plane, subdivided, and point instance from a collection. How do I make every instance on a random height (z-axis) from a minimum and a maximum value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [Attribute Randomize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_randomize.html) node set to *Vector* and *Add* between your [Point Distribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_distribute.html) and [Point Instance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_instance.html) nodes. Type in `position` as the attribute.

Note : You need V2.93 + in order to change the Attribute Randomize mode, otherwise the point locations will be overwritten by the node.

Example tree :

[image]

Playing with the inputs :

[image]

Explanation :

The Attribute Randomize node will create a new random Vector for each point in the geometry, before instanciation. Since the mode is set to *Add*, it will add this random vector to the points positions. Each vertex will have a random Vector added, and the amplitude of the random value will be contained between the Min and Max inputs. Here we forced a Min of (0, 0, - amplitude) and a Max of (0, 0, amplitude). Thus, the points will be displaced along only the Z axis (because both X and Y axes are set to 0) by a value between -amplitude and +amplitude. In the end, it means the origin of each instanced object in the Point Instance node will be translated by a random value along the Z axis.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following, the instances all go to the world origin. How can I fix this?

Comment: In the Attribute Randomize node, set the mode to *Add* instead of *Replace*

Comment: I do not see that option, maybe i'm in an older version. I'm gonna update. Thanks for the help I appreciate it!

Comment: Oh, right, this has been added in the latest 2.93 release ! :)

Comment: Ok it works! I'd love to understand how and why. Thank you!

Comment: @WardD Added an explanation at the end of the answer, hopefully it's understandable